# Increase Size of Ordered and Unordered list

Tags: css, html

When I increase the size of text the bullets in unordered list and numbers in ordered list remains the same size. I want to increase the size of these markers.
Can anyone tell me how?

```
      <ul>
      <li class="font-large">Text</li>
      </ul>
```

Here I've changed the font size to 30px

I want to increase the size of bullets in ul and numbers in ol to match with the size of Text

Comment: Can you give us the CSS definition and what result you get with a prtscr ?

Comment: I'm really not sure what are you trying to do, can you be more specific? "Size of text the bullets" -part is really not clear. You want to increase only the size of the text? Then just add a span inside the li-element and style that.